App Status: Rejected , Issue found: No full-size app banner and/or icon ANDROIDTV
App Status: Rejected
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Issue found: No full-size app banner and/or icon
Your app should contain a full-size app banner and icon that is visible in the launcher. We are targeting 1080P, which we consider xhdpi. Apps should include the banner in the xhdpi (320 dpi) drawables folder with a size of (320px × 180px) and the icon with a size of (512px x512px). Please refer to our Home screen banner.
The title should help users identify apps in the launcher. Please refer to our Visual design and user interaction documentation for more information.
Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Version code xxxxx: In-app experience

About the Android TV App Quality Guidelines
We do not accept apps into Android TV that don't adhere to Android TV App Quality Guidelines.
please help me.
Its an Androidtv app.
What files are missing?
previous version contains same files.Recent app updates have been published.
Has Google policy changed in April 2024?

Did you follow this section? https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#icon-and-banner
